# Entity Framework DB First not adding table

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following table in the database that uses a composite primary key and also has foreign keys to other tables. We are switching from LINQ2SQL to entity framework but for some reason this table won't be pulled in. Both columns are not null, so I believe it should be a valid primary key.

Here is what the table definition is when creating the table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WH_Subscriber]
(
    [EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WaLoId] [int] NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EmployeeId] ASC, [WaLoId] ASC)
            WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                  IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                  ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WH_Subscriber] WITH CHECK 
      ADD FOREIGN KEY([EmployeeId])
      REFERENCES [dbo].[WH_Employee] ([EmployeeId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WH_Subscriber] WITH CHECK 
      ADD FOREIGN KEY([WaLoId])
      REFERENCES [dbo].[WH_WaLo] ([WaLoId])
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed like the composite primary key was invalid but I'm not 100% certain why. However I recreated the table and added an Identity column and applied the primary key and it showed up. Example below

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WH_Subscriber](
    [SubsciberId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WaLoId] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SubsciberId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON),
 CONSTRAINT [uq_WH_Subscriber] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeId] ASC,
    [WaLoId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

GO
```